# How to link Twilio Voice with Taskrouter?

Tags: php, json, xml, twilio, twilio-twiml

We are using Taskrouter and Voice from Twilio. We've made them into 2 seperate modules and now I want to link them together.

The question is, when a call comes in and after it's gone through the process to go to the right worker by Taskrouter, how do I let the worker pickup the phone and let the call go through? (Using Javscript WebRTC)

I've got both javascript libaries (Taskrouter, Voice) loaded into the browser, and I've used the libary to accept the call and listen/speak.

So what I want is, when someone calls the number attached to the Twilio Taskrouter Task, the right Worker needs to be chosen and then that worker has to be able to pickup that call. I would like to be pointed in the right direction (docs/example code)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you accept the reservation using the TaskRouter JavaScript you can use [`reservation.dequeue`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-js#reservation-dequeue) with the parameter `dequeueTo` set to the Client name of your worker. That will perform the telephony operations to connect the call to your Twilio Client instance.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: That's all I really wanted to know, thank you!

Comment: can someone please suggest me on the below issue that I am facing with twilio-video http://stackoverflow.com/q/41709800/2534233