# Twilio Video - “Failed to connect to room with error: SIP error 403”

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, twilio, callkit

I get this error “Failed to connect to room with error: SIP error 403”, when I try to make a call from one iOS client to another while using twilio [video sdk](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift) for swift.

I am able to make a call (Xcode to mobile & mobile to mobile) when I use manually generated twilio access tokens (obtained from Twilio console) and insert them in the client app. However, I get the above error when I try to get the token programatically from Twilio via NodeJS server using the below server code provided by Twilio. The error persists even when using secure connection (HTTPS) to obtain the token from Twilio.

The below is the log from Xcode,

```
2017-01-13 07:30:47.625 VideoCall[39299:25726155] Attempting to connect to room Optional("testRoom")
2017-01-13 07:30:47.625 VideoCall[39299:25726155] provider:didActivateAudioSession:
2017-01-13 07:30:51.255 VideoCall[39299:25726155] Failed to connect to room with error: SIP error 403
2017-01-13 07:30:51.272 VideoCall[39299:25726155] provider:didDeactivateAudioSession:
2017-01-13 07:32:52.168 VideoCall[39299:25729470] ERROR:TwilioVideo:[Signaling]:RESIP::TRANSPORT: Got TLS read ret=0 error=6 error:00000006:invalid library (0):OPENSSL_internal:public key routines
```

NodeJS server code (provided by Twilio)

```
var express     = require('express');
var router      = express.Router();
var AccessToken = require('twilio').AccessToken;

// Substitute your Twilio AccountSid and ApiKey details
var ACCOUNT_SID = 'accountSid';
var API_KEY_SID = 'apiKeySid';
var API_KEY_SECRET = 'apiKeySecret';
var TWILIO_CONFIGURATION_SID = 'twilioConfigurationSid';

router.get('/getTwilioVideoAccessToken', function(req, res, next) {
    // Create an Access Token
    var accessToken = new AccessToken(
      ACCOUNT_SID,
      API_KEY_SID,
      API_KEY_SECRET
    );

      var identity = 'example-user'; 

    // Set the Identity of this token
    accessToken.identity = identity;

    // Grant access to Conversations
    var grant = new AccessToken.ConversationGrant();
    grant.configurationProfileSid = TWILIO_CONFIGURATION_SID;
    accessToken.addGrant(grant);

    // Serialize the token as a JWT
    var jwt = accessToken.toJwt();
    console.log(jwt);
    res.json({"token": jwt, "statusCode" : 200, "identity":identity})
});
```

**Solution:**

Twilio customer support had suggested that I was using an incorrect API_KEY_SECRET, which was causing the error, as also pointed out by @Aubtin Samai. 
One can generate the API_KEY_SECRET by following the instructions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41754420/2534233).

Comment: What's the code you're using to retrieve the access token from the server and initiate your Video client?

Comment: I am using the sample app provided by Twilio, which retrieves the access token from the app server and initiates the video client. https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift/tree/master/VideoCallKitQuickStart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm correct in assuming these values are not placeholders for the real ones (it's a 403 error), you need to add your API credentials to your NodeJS script...

```
var ACCOUNT_SID = 'accountSid';
var API_KEY_SID = 'apiKeySid';
var API_KEY_SECRET = 'apiKeySecret';
var TWILIO_CONFIGURATION_SID = 'twilioConfigurationSid';
```

Comment: I have added API Credentials to the NodeJS Script, I have not shown them here.

Comment: Are you sure you put the API credentials in the correct spots? Do you have credits in your account?

Comment: Hi how to know other user is online or offline .may you have me please?